# Sphinx4 won't recognize full speech if .wav file duration is long

Tags: java, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

We are doing a project which user's answers are saved as .wav files and evaluated after. We have created grammars for each and every question. There are two questions we are having a recognition problem. Problems are probably the same since user must speak approximately 7-8 seconds for both of these questions.

This is the grammar file that we are using for one of the questions;

```
#JSGF V1.0;grammar Question8; public <Question8> = (  one hundred | ninety three | eighty six | seventy nine | seventy two | sixty five) * ;
```

Here, user must count numbers backwards by 7s. It recognizes fine if I speak too fast. When I speak slowly, for instance after saying "one hundred" and wait for 1 second and carry on until sixty five like this, it will only recognize one hundred and it won't recognize other words.

Two main parts are responsible for these processes:

The class that we created for microphone;

```
public final class SpeechRecorder {
static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
static Microphone mic = new Microphone(16000, 16, 1, true, true, false, 10, true, "average", 0, "default", 6400);

public static void startMic() {
    mic.initialize();
    mic.startRecording();
    mic.getAudioFormat();
    mic.getUtterance();
    System.out.println("Audio Format is" + mic.getAudioFormat());

}

public static void stopMic(String questionName) {
    mic.stopRecording();
    Utterance u = mic.getUtterance();

    try {
        u.save("Resources/Answers/" + questionName + ".wav", AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getAnswersOfSpeech(String question) throws IOException {
    Evaluation.disableLogMessages();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration.setGrammarPath("resource:/Grammer");
    configuration.setGrammarName(question);
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);
    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("Resources/Answers/" + question + ".wav"));
    SpeechResult Result = recognizer.getResult();
    String speechWords = Result.getHypothesis();

    return speechWords;
}

public static String getSavedAnswer(int question) {

    return User.getAnswers(question);

}
```

}

This is where we save user's answer as .wav files into our resources.

```
btn_microphone.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            click++;
            if (click % 2 == 1) {
                SpeechRecorder.startMic();
                btn_microphone.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Resources/Images/record.png"));
            } else {
                SpeechRecorder.stopMic("Question" + Integer.toString(question));

                btn_Next.setVisible(true);
                btn_microphone.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Resources/Images/microphone.png"));

                lbl_speechAnswer.setVisible(true);
                try {
                    userAnswer = SpeechRecorder.getAnswersOfSpeech("Question" + Integer.toString(question));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (userAnswer.equals("")) {
                    lbl_speechAnswer.setText(
                            "<html>No answer was given, click on microphone button to record again</html>");
                } else {
                    lbl_speechAnswer.setText("<html>Your answer is " + userAnswer
                            + ", click on microphone button to record again</html>");
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

I don't how can we overcome this problem. I would be so grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop as in [transcriber demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/7ed6d8893e8aefc2db78e58a6b342f901b4ae7b6/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java#L55):

```
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
```